# url - retrieve all parameters starts with a unique name

Tags: java, url, web, parameters

I am working on a java web application where i come across a strange scenario, like the one mentioned below.

I have a url - where i can expect a list of parameters in which a group of parameters starts with the same name - but we are not sure on the total number of such parameters.

Let me explain the same with a simple example.

http://test.com/test.action?stud_0=test6&age_0=12&stud_1=test4&age_1=16&stud_2=test5&age_2=14

please can you advise how can i get all the student names in a list and then all student age in a list in order?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

1. Create a `URL` with the url text you have.
2. `URL.getQuery()` will return the whole query part (after the `?` character).
3. Split the query at the parameter separator character (`String.split("&")`. This will give you an array of `"paramname=paramvalue"` strings.
4. Iterate over the array, and split each element at the `'='` character. This will give you an array of 2 strings: the parameter name and parameter value.
5. Decode each param name and param value using the `URLDecoder.decode()` method to get back a valid text.
6. Put the parameters that start with `"stud"` into one array, and parameters that start with `"age"` into an another array, to the index specified by the number being in the parameter name after the underscore (`'_'`) character.
7. Storing elements at the specified index in Step 6 will ensure that the elements in the array are in order, if you need a list instead of the array, use `Collections.asList()`.